# gRPC Java - Listening for successful calls on server

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

I am looking for a way to capture when a call is completed on the server and no errors were thrown.

I understand that `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` exists, however,`onComplete` is called when an exception is thrown.

My use case is for transaction management.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it currently only triggers `onComplete()`. There is [a bug](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/3746) filed for that. If it's fixed, you can probably get `onCancel()` instead.

For now, you can wrap the `ServerCall` with `SimpleForwardingServerCall` in your `ServerInterceptor`, and override `close()`. If the RPC ends successfully, `OK` will be passed to `close()`.